# Filtering DataFrame on groups where count of element is different than 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a DataFrame having the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'brand':['A','B','X','C','D','X','X','E','F','X']})

print(df)

   group brand
0      1     A
1      1     B
2      1     X
3      2     C
4      2     D
5      2     X
6      2     X
7      3     E
8      3     F
9      3     X
```

My goal is to view only the groups having **exactly one** brand `X` associated to them. Since group number 2 has two observations equal to brand `X`, it should be filtered out from the resulting DataFrame.

The output should look like this:

```
   group brand
0      1     A
1      1     B
2      1     X
3      3     E
4      3     F
5      3     X
```

I know I should do a `groupby` on the group column and then filter those groups having a count of `X` different than 1. The filtering part is where I struggle. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to check if `brand` is equal to `X` , then groupby and `transform` `sum` and filter groups in which `X` count is equal to 1:

```
df[df['brand'].eq('X').groupby(df['group']).transform('sum').eq(1)]
```

---

```
   group brand
0      1     A
1      1     B
2      1     X
7      3     E
8      3     F
9      3     X
```

Answer (score 8):

This should work as well

```
df[df.groupby(['group'])['brand'].transform('sum').str.count('X').eq(1)]
```

**Output**

```
 group  brand
0   1   A
1   1   B
2   1   X
7   3   E
8   3   F
9   3   X
```

Answer (score 6):

Groupby column and apply a simple filter of count of `'X'` character in the group equal to 1

```
df.groupby('group').filter(lambda x: x['brand'].str.count('X').sum() == 1)
```

Output

```
   group brand
0      1     A
1      1     B
2      1     X
7      3     E
8      3     F
9      3     X
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution with [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
df[df['group'].map(pd.crosstab(df['group'],df['brand'])['X'].eq(1))]

#   group brand
#0      1     A
#1      1     B
#2      1     X
#7      3     E
#8      3     F
#9      3     X
```

We can also use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`Series.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df.merge(df.loc[df.brand.eq('X'),'group'].drop_duplicates(keep = False),on='group')
#   group brand
#0      1     A
#1      1     B
#2      1     X
#3      3     E
#4      3     F
#5      3     X
```